# Comparing String.Index values

Tags: string, macos, swift

Is it possible to compare two `String.Index` values in Swift? I'm trying to process a string character by character, and several times I need to check if I am at the end of the string. I've tried just doing

```
while (currentIndex < string.endIndex) {
    //do things...
    currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
}
```

Which complained about type conversions. Then, I tried defining and overload for `<` as such:

```
@infix func <(lhs: String.Index, rhs: String.Index) -> Bool {
    var ret = true //what goes here?
    return ret
}
```

Which gets rid of compilation errors, but I have no clue what to do in order to compare `lhs` and `rhs` properly. Is this the way I should go about using `String.Index`, or is there a better way to compare them?

Comment: Overriding operators is not the solution.

Comment: Well obviously overriding `<` won't solve anything, but that's how I'd like to be able to compare two `String.Index` values, if possible. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: In Swift 3, it seems `<` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is the `distance()` function:

```
var string = "Hello World"
var currentIndex = string.startIndex

while (distance(currentIndex, string.endIndex) >= 0) {
  println("currentIndex: \(currentIndex)")
  currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
}
```

Beware `distance()` has `O(N)` performance, so avoid it for large strings. However, the entire String class doesn't currently handle large strings anyway — you should probably switch to `CFString` if performance is critical.

Using an operator overload is a bad idea, but just as a learning exercise this is how you'd do it:

```
var string = "Hello World"
var currentIndex = string.startIndex

@infix func <(lhs: String.Index, rhs: String.Index) -> Bool {
  return distance(lhs, rhs) > 0
}

while (currentIndex < string.endIndex) {
  currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. `O(n)` performance is sort of annoying, though likely won't cause any issues for the strings I'm working with. Why would you say that using an operator overload is a bad idea?

Comment: @Jumhyn Beware the String class is currently *full* of `O(n)` performance problems. You will run into them no matter what. This seems to be a general design flaw in the class. No doubt they will fix it one day, but for now we just need to accept it - or use NS/CFString.

Comment: Later when someone else is working on the code they will not understand the usage. That compounded with lot's of developers overloading all sorts of things is a recipe for disaster. The best solution is the most clear solution, the one that will later cause fewer WTFs/minute.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert But `CFString` and `NSString` both have major problems dealing with emoji, surrogate pairs and composites such as flag characters, none of which are representable in a UTF-16 unichar. Emoji in particular are showing up with increasing frequency.

Comment: String.utf16 gives you an alternate representation, which is closer to how NSString and CFString indexing works. You can use integer indices and do math on the indices, but at this time, it lacks functions for finding and matching strings so you will have to implement those yourself. It also suffers from all the downsides of NSString and CFString.

Comment: Also, it seems somewhat arbitrary to me which items receive global functions. For instance, why is `distance` a global function for two `T: ForwardIndex` and not a method `distanceTo(other: T)` of the `ForwardIndex` protocol?

Comment: @Jumhyn, that threw me a bit as I assumed it was a global function but Xcode wouldn't compile it, turns out it's a function on the `String` the indices belong to! So I think the original code won't compile, or at least not in the latest Swift/Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

String indexes support `=` and `!=`. String indexes are an opaque type, not integers and can not be compared like integers.

Use: `if (currentIndex != string.endIndex)`

```
var currentIndex = string.startIndex
while (currentIndex != string.endIndex) {
    println("currentIndex: \(currentIndex)")
    currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
}
```

Comment: I realise this is the proper answer, but as a side question, is there some way to check if an index precedes or succeeds another index?

Comment: If you do this you will miss the last index.

Comment: If you call `currentIndex.successor` only you can not miss the last character. But please file a bug report, this is a Beta. Also note that there was a large change inBeta4 so there is a good chance that there will be improvements coming. The whole unicode issue still has a lot of problems but Apple with Swift is addressing many.

Comment: Yeah, there definitely are some limitations in String. The only project where I need to do complex string operations I'm sticking with CFString. I suspect some of the more advanced things I'm taking advantage of will never be possible using String.

Comment: The problem with `CFString` is that it isn't going to handle emoji, surrogate pairs not composite such as flag characters, none of which are representable in a UTF-16 `unichar`.

Comment: That's just not true, CFString handles emoji just fine. Here's a screenshot of CFString loading one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147461/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-04%20at%2011.53.43%20am.png which is later drawn using core text (the part where I am using swift): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147461/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-04%20at%2011.57.52%20am.png

Comment: It is when you need to get an index that there is a problem, a single character can span several unichars thus indexing into a `CFString` can point into the middle of a character. As long as the entire string is utilized as a whole everything works. unicode is a 21 bit encoding and emoji fall into needing 17 bits. Except comparing strings that may look identical but one is composed and the other isn't. Check out this [blog](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/) by Ole Begemann.

Comment: Consider the string: "Thistest". 10 character, 14 unichars.

Comment: It works fine as long as you understand how unicode works and handle it properly. In my case I'm reading the NSData object to find glyph bounds, since I need to know the character positions before creating a CFString object (which can be large enough it won't fit in RAM if I loaded the entire data set into CFString). It's only a few lines of code to check if you're inside a unicode character and walk back to the beginning of it.

Comment: But as I said, I'm doing some pretty unusual stuff. It's not often you need to deal with 50GB length strings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this REPL/Playground example should illuminate what you (and others) need to know about working with the String.Index concept.

```
// This will be our working example
let exampleString = "this is a string"

// And here we'll call successor a few times to get an index partway through the example
var someIndexInTheMiddle = exampleString.startIndex
for _ in 1...5 {
    someIndexInTheMiddle = someIndexInTheMiddle.successor()
}

// And here we will iterate that string and detect when our current index is relative in one of three different possible ways to the character selected previously
println("\n\nsomeIndexInTheMiddle = \(exampleString[someIndexInTheMiddle])")
for var index: String.Index = exampleString.startIndex; index != exampleString.endIndex; index = index.successor() {
    println(" - \(exampleString[index])")
    if index != exampleString.startIndex && index.predecessor() == someIndexInTheMiddle {
        println("current character comes after someIndexInTheMiddle")
    } else if index == someIndexInTheMiddle {
        println("current character is the one indicated by someIndexInTheMiddle")
    } else if index != exampleString.endIndex && index.successor() == someIndexInTheMiddle {
        println("Current character comes before someIndexinTheMiddle")
    }
}
```

Hopefully that provides the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever way you decide to iterator over a `String`, you will immediately want to capture the iteration in a function that can be repeatedly invoked while using a closure applied to each string character.  As in:

```
extension String {
  func each (f: (Character) -> Void) {
    for var index = self.startIndex;
        index < self.endIndex;
        index = index.successor() {
      f (string[index])
    }
  }
}
```

Apple already provides these for C-Strings and will for general strings as soon as they get character access solidified.